# Sort the 'last' output by month

Tags: bash, sort, last

I know that the command last | tac is enough, but I want to do it using the sort command. I cannot sort it by column, it always sorts the first one only. 
Using bash on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you can't rely on fields, so you'd need to rely on character column

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
stephane pts/0        :0               Fri Aug  1 09:48 - 14:34 (17+04:45)
stephane pts/13       :0               Fri Aug  1 16:27 - 13:51 (20+21:24)
```

From that:

```
last | sort -k1.44,1.46M -k1.48,1.49n -k51
```

Note that the `M` flag to sort on month names is not standard but available in several `sort` implementations including GNU `sort` (the one typically found on ArchLinux). Note that `sort` interprets the month names in the current locale, while `last` always outputs English month names, so you may want to run `sort` under `LC_TIME=C` if in a non-English locale.

Comment: The M flag in sort (compare as months) is available on Sun OS/Solaris too.

Comment: @DimitreRadoulov, indeed, it's even in HP/UX, so it's probably not a GNU extension as I thought it was. I've changed the wording.